# Which software gets the fastest rendering times?

Tags: video-editor

I'm sure there are benchmarks out there, but I'm not sure where to find them. Circa 2006 I was holding on to Vegas 6 without letting go because I could see very noticeable differences in its rendering times. (It's super fast!) And I've made fun of people who tough it out with Final Cut or Premiere for its atrociously slow rendering times. I'm just curious if anyone benchmarks this stuff.

Comment: I don't think this question works here, as any answer will change as updates are made to render code. Very localised, and you'd be best looking at benchmarking sites, if anyone does them.

Comment: If there is a good site that does benchmarking, I don't know what it is. And if someone does know what it is, it will be helpful if they shared the link. It's more of a thought-provoking question. I'd like to keep thinking about it.

Comment: Aww. Come on. You guys closed the question on me without providing something constructive? That's weak. You know this question is going to come up again and again. Next time, BE HELPFUL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is necessarily possible to get meaningful benchmarks for video editing render times now.  With the advent of system's using GPU processing for rendering, the already complicated field got even tougher.  There are simply too many variables.  It depends on the performance of particular effects and plugins and what kind of hardware and bandwidth needs there are within the project.  Since the needs of projects differ so greatly, I don't see how a meaningful benchmark could be established unless it was to try benchmarking individual filters within the applications.

In general, the new render engine in Premiere is very fast though.  Even for software only it works quick, but with GPU acceleration, it gets pretty crazy.  Running software only, I can run a full resolution all I frame 1080p 24fps signal with color correction applied through my tower with fairly minimal frame drops.  I'm unfortunately PC only so I can't compare to FCPX.

Comment: Nice one AJ Henderson. I have started documenting my render times based on Vegas Pro 10 on a 32 bit Win7, no GPU, but CPU is quad core, with 4 GB of ram. E.g., 2:43 runtime with up to 6 video tracks (some portions only have 2 video tracks running at the same time) and 3 stereo music tracks: 16 minutes for 720p mpeg 2 m2t and about 32 minutes for 1080p mp4 (7.5 Mbps).

Comment: Thanks for trying to tackle the question, AJ. Since this discussion board is still in Beta, I thought I'd see how well received a question like this would be because I know how hard it is to answer and thus I've never asked before! Let's keep the conversation going. There are a few obvious things that help: GPU and the newer Premiere. Windows, maybe. I don't know! That's why I'm curious. :)